# Rotating a modal overCurrentContext View messes up

Tags: ios, swift

If I rotate the device, the View presented with overCurrentContext isn't updated to fit the rotated device until I switch to another View in the TabBarController and come back.
Weirdly enough, the problem doesn't show up if the View is presented through the Storyboard but only if I present the View programmatically.

```
let proViewVC:ProViewViewController = ProViewViewController(nibName: "ProViewVC", bundle: nil)
proViewVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.navigationController?.present(proViewVC, animated: false, completion:nil)
```

I tried to use something like this:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Try to use viewWillTransition and refresh view once rotation is completed

Comment: @KishanBhatiya `self.proViewVC.view.setNeedsLayout()` and `self.proViewVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()` don't do anything in this case

Comment: Are you using collectionView? if yes then try to invalidate collection view layout yourCollection.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: @KishanBhatiya no the proViewVC is a regular View which contains another View and a ScrollView

Comment: Try to set scrollView's contentSize in viewDidLayoutSubviews() like YourScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: YourScrollView.bounds.width, height: height)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was setting the presented view controller's view frame in viewWillTransition like:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate { _ in
        let newFrame = self.presentingViewController?.view.bounds ?? .zero
        self.view.frame = newFrameUIApplication.isLandscape, newFrame)
    } completion: { _ in }
}
```

Strangely, the presentingViewController view's bounds seemed not to be right in the completion, only inside the first closure.